# Submit a php form and display its result on div without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

First of all, thank you for your kind help.

I have tried almost everything I found on stackoverflow but I cannot get this to work.

I created a form to send a text to the webmaster (instead of an email). So I have my index.php file

```
    <style>
    .result{
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color:  #ccc;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>


<form id="contact-form" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="" placeholder="Name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" />    
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="example@yourdomain.com" required="required" autocomplete="off" /> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <textarea  id="message" name="message" value="" placeholder="20 characters max." required="required" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"  ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" name="submit" />
        *indicates a required field 
    </div>

</form>

<div class="result"></div>
```

And this is my jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#contact-form').submit(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                type:"POST",
                url:"sendtext.php",
                data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
                success: function(response){$(".result").appendTo(response)}

            });
            //return false;
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

The script does not work. If I put   `action = sendtext.php` in the `<form>` it will work perfectly but it will take me to sendtext.php and `echo` the message.

What I want is to show the `echo` in the `<div class="result"></div>`.

Again thank you for your help.

---

**UPDATE # 1**
After a few comments...

this is what I have so far...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({ 
                type:"POST",
                url:"sendtext.php",
                data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
                success: function(response){$(".result").append(response)}

            });
            //return false;
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

---

**Update 2**

After reading all the comments and try different options, no success just yet! I did what @guy suggested, and it worked but I want to use `form` and `submit`.

Again, I appreciate all your time you put to help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when you add sendText.php as the action, your jQuery **will** execute because the form is submitted so that will work... **BUT** it will also take you to the page of the form's *action field*. What you want to do is **not call submit** but just make a button instead and have the jQuery listen to a *click* on that button.

Instead of:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" name="submit" />
```

Change it to a regular button:

```
<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

Then in your jQuery, change the line

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function() {
```

to

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
```

Also, change appendTo to html and then the result should show up in your result div.

----EDIT----

This worked for me:

```
<style>
  .result{
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color:  #ccc;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    color: #fff;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }
</style>

<div id="contact-form" >
<div>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="" placeholder="Name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="example@yourdomain.com" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div>
    <textarea  id="message" name="message" value="" placeholder="20 characters max." required="required" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"  ></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    *indicates a required field
</div>

</div>

<div class="result"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#submit-button').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
               type:"post",
               url:"sendText.php",
               data:  $("#contact-form").serialize(),
               success: function(response){
                   $(".result").html(response);
               }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: after trying this, when I click the button, it refreshes the page. No results, no `echo` no nothing.

Comment: That's impossible. You're not submitting anything as far as the form is concerned so why would it refresh the page? You're sure you don't have type='submit' on the button?

Comment: here is my live demo following your suggestions.. [demo](http://robertocabrera.us/send-text/index.php)

Comment: Make it NOT a form, make it a div instead. Check my edited answer.

Comment: It does - see [demo](http://www.smartpage.me/so.php), please mark as correct answer :)

Comment: you are right...it works...but is not the kind of answer I am looking for. I want to use a form not a div, use submit, not a click...your approach is great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you need it in a form? Could you at least up vote my answer since it is correct? :)

Comment: I decided I will go with your solution. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use the the preventDefault() function so that the form doesn't do the redirection on submit.
After that, use append() instead of appendTo()

> $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
>
> > e.preventDefault();

Comment: after trying your suggestion, it still does not work.

Comment: This should work. Make sure to include the `e` in `.submit(function(e)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(".result").appendTo(response)
```

to:

```
$(".result").append(response)
```

Comment: after I tried this, the page reloads but no response nor result from the sendtext.php, in other words, it is not calling the php file.

Comment: @bob89 Are you sure your `url` is correct? The `sendtext.php` is the same directory as your current js file?

Comment: my script is in the same `index.php` file. Also the `sendtext.php` is in the same directory as index.php. As I mentioned before If I add `action = "sendtext.php"` to the `<form>` tag, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
 $(".result").html(response);
```

instead of

```
 $(".result").appendTo(response)
```

Jaavscript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-form').submit(function() {             
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST",
            url:"sendtext.php",
            data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                 $(".result").html(response);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });        
});
```

Comment: after I tried this, the page reloads but no response nor result from the `sendtext.php`, in other words, it is not calling the php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `appendTo` in success callback is backward. In your example, you are trying to append the `.result` element to the `response` variable. Should be:

`success: function(response){ response.appendTo(".result")}`