# PHP form submit without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I wanted to have the contact form in my webpage but I wanted it so that it does not refresh or open a new tab while submission.
I followed this question [Submit a php form and display its result on div without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192923/submit-a-php-form-and-display-its-result-on-div-without-reloading-page) and implimented it.

It's working now. It sends an email but does not take values from the contact form. ie: The email body should be

```
Name: (name entered in the form)
Email: (email entered in the form)
Message: (message entered in the form)
```

But it's always :

```
Name: 
Email: 
Message:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<title>FeedBack Form With Email Functionality</title>
  
<style>

.result{
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color:  #ccc;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    color: #fff;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }

#contactme{
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 width:833px;
 height:450px;
 background:#FFF;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#FFF;
}

#sub_button:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
}

#sub_button {
    background:#F00;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 161px;
    height: 28px;
}
</style>
</head> 

<body>


<div id="contactme" style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" />
 </div>

 <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="example@yourdomain.com" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
 </div>

 <div>
    <textarea  id="message" name="message" value="" placeholder="20 characters max." required="required" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"  ></textarea>
 </div>
            
    <div id="sub_button" style="position:absolute; top:30px; right:30px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="result"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sub_button').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
               type:"post",
               url:"insert1.php",
               data:  $("#contactme").serialize(),
               success: function(response){
                   $(".result").html(response);
               }
         });
      });
   });
</script>

 </body> 
 <!-- body ends here -->
 
 </html>
```

Here's my PHP :

```html
<?php

// Get values from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$data=$_POST['message'];

$to = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "From The Website";
$message = " Name: " . $name . "\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Message: " . $data;


$from = $name;
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
 echo "Message was sent successfully!";
  echo '<script>alert("Message was sent successfully!");</script>';
  
}else{
  echo '<script>alert("Error in sending message! Please mail your message to email@gmail.com");</script>';
  echo "Error in sending message! Please mail your message to email@gmail.com";
}

echo '<script>
self.close();
</script>';


?>
```

Comment: You need Ajax for that. Have a look again at the topic you are referring to.

Comment: @callback could you be a little more specific? do I need to link any other library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a  html form element instead of a div should do the trick:

replace:

```
<div id="contactme" style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif">
    <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

with

```
<form id="contactme" method="post" style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif">
     <!-- [...] -->
</form>
```

should work. For more information see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<div id = 'test'><input name = 'zzz' value = 'zzz'/></div>").serialize()
""
```

Gives a blank value as an output, however

```
$("<form id = 'test'><input name = 'zzz' value = 'zzz'/></form>").serialize()
"zzz=zzz"
```

Therefore, your `<div id = "contact-me">` should turn into a form and in the click handler you would need to call `preventDefault()` on the event.

```
$("#test").on('submit',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//Your ajax logic
});
```

This would work too.

Comment: The funny thing is, that there is no submit button used, but a onClick event on a div. So there is no reason for using on submit with `e.preventDefault();`. But you are right, using a submit button and suppress the default behaviour is more common.

Comment: Ideally a submit button is used. And it is better to catch the submit event rather than a submit button onclick action is because submit event can handle submits from multiple buttons if they are they, although having multiple submit buttons is seldom done, I find it to be a better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Run this HTML its working fine.

Use HTML `form` data instead of a `div`.

```
<form id="contactme" method="post">
    <div style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif">
        <div>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="example@yourdomain.com" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div>
        <textarea  id="message" name="message" value="" placeholder="20 characters max." required="required" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"  ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="sub_button" style="position:absolute; top:30px; right:30px;"></div>
 </div>   
</form>
<div class="result"></div>
```